# hdfs: command not found with Hadoop2.9.0

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to install hadoop with [the tutorial from tutorialspoint.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hbase/hbase_installation.htm)
I just sucessfully installed hadoop2.9.0. I then tried to set up the namenode using the command “hdfs namenode -format” as follows.

```
$ hdfs namenode -format
```

Yet the terminal answered me :

```
bash: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs: Permission denied
```

So I did :

```
mike@mike-thinks:~$ sudo chown -R mike /usr/local/hadoop
```

But even with it I still get :

```
mike@mike-thinks:~$ sudo hdfs namenode -format
sudo: hdfs: command not found
```

Comment: If you do `/bin/ls -l /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs`, you will probably see that the "eXecute" permission is missing. `sudo chmod +x  /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs` will fix tyhat.

Comment: @waltinator, you're damn right !

Answer (score 0):

I hope this error is resolved by now, but this error occurs because the hdfs path may not be set, so first check hdfs path by using this command,

```
which hdfs
```

if path is not set, then check the environment variable in ~/.bash_profile if it PATH is written like this,

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

change it to this PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

then check the your hdfs path, if it is set by using which command(as shown above) Then your problem might get resolved. Hope this helps!